# Mobile First CSS to Display Video Full Screen

Tags: html, css, video

I am developing a website and always use mobile first.

I am not sure of the right way to display this.

As its mobile first, the css would go like this:

```
#bgvid { display: none; }
```

And then my media query would have:

```
#bgvid { display:block; }
```

But the problem is the video is not covering the full screen, it's leaving gaps in the top and bottom.

I don't want mobiles to see the video. So what would the correct way be to display this full screen.

Comment: is this what you're tying to do? http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video